# Place a Spinner in Action bar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, spinner

My question is simple, how would you go about to set a Spinner/dropdown list in the Action bar (in place of the title)?

I know there are other similar questions on here but all the answers I could find were very old and used deprecated code or linked to some guide in the Android docs that isn't there anymore.

Comment: What was wrong with my question, why is it downvoted?

Comment: you can add your custom view as a action bar and set spinner in it

Comment: I have a recyclerview in my activity so I dont want to add other elements in to my activity.xml otherwise I recyclerview wont be able to have "match_parent" as height.

Comment: are you using constraint layout or others?

Comment: Yeah constraint layout

Comment: so you can easily implement design with custom action bar with recylerview.

Comment: Can you provide this solution as an answer, because I'm actually not sure what you mean that I should do, I have not been programming for very long. Also then I can accept your answer if it works.

Comment: this solution is for toolbar , if you want to it with custom view then i will update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this one

call this from activity on create method and implement AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener also.

```
   String[] weeks = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "thursday","Sunday"}

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_app_bar_spinner);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMethodInterviews);
    Spinner spinnerSecond = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMethodSecond);
    ArrayAdapter<String>   spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            R.layout.custom_title, android.R.id.text1, weeks);

    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.cutom_spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    spinnerSecond.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinnerSecond.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

main_Activity.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_top"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerMethodInterviews"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerMethodSecond"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_top"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

custom_spinner.xml

```
   <CheckedTextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

custom_title.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Comment: Getting an error: `ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();`, the variable is requiring a ActionBar yet it is receiving the appcompat version so they are incompatible.

Comment: so remove action bar and use a view or layout, and other process will be same

Comment: Yes please do, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: check my updated answer, use main_Activity.xml instead of actionbar.xml, i have used custom app bar and also used recyclerview.

Comment: There is no `custom_app_bar_spinner` layout file and also the `this` statements on `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
 spinnerSecond.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);` are causing errors.

Comment: custom_app_bar_spinner is main_Activity.xml, and implement AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListene also in your activity.

Comment: Got it. What about the `this` statements, also where exactly do I implement the `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`?

Comment: when you extend appcompact activity then also implement this listener

Comment: like View.onclicklistener